# How to reduce url in codeigniter using routes or htaccess file

Tags: php

i want to convert my url
http://192.168.2.123/ca_practice_management/dashboards/department_dashboard/index/depid00103

to
http://192.168.2.123/ca_practice_management/depid00103

what should be the htaccess file or routes.php

Answer (score 0):

That is not codeigniter config if we ignoring replace project folder with htdocs your best solution is using virtual host

```
$route['folder/controller/(:any)'] = "controller/(:any)";
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html

Comment: http://192.168.2.123/ca_practice_management/organization/department_details/link_department/depid00103